# How to make Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDn change window tabs

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am running GNOME 3.4 (Debian 7.0) and my laptop ([Gigabyte Q2532](http://www.gigabyte.co.za/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3793#kf)), unlike all those I've used before, doesn't change application tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Pg Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Pg Dn</kbd>. This forces me to use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0...9</kbd>, which is not always convenient. Is there something wrong with my laptop? Is this normal? How to remedy? My layout is set to `English (US)`.

Note that I tried this with a fresh user, and still get the same issue. I'm also using GNOME 3 fallback mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`GtkNotebook`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkNotebook.html) defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PageDown</kbd> for switching tabs (hardcoded in [gtk/gtknotebook.c](https://gitorious.org/ghelp/gtk/blobs/ccdc3c18028925565f252e7259aefe2b27e3ec2e/gtk/gtknotebook.c#line1115)).

The problem is your keys are on the numpad, so they have different keynames/keysyms, i.e.: `KP_Page_Up` (instead of `Page_Up`) and `KP_Page_Down` (instead of `Page_Down`). Remapping the keys should fix it. I have no numpad on my XPS 15 to test but something like this should work:

```sh
xmodmap -e 'keysym KP_Prior = Prior' -e 'keysym KP_Next = Next'
```

You could also patch the source code, replacing all occurrences of `GDK_KEY_Page_Up/GDK_KEY_Page_Down` with `GDK_KEY_KP_Page_Up/GDK_KEY_KP_Page_Down` in `gtknotebook.c`

---

Since you're on Gnome, you can make it permanent by adding it to your start-up programs. In terminal, run `gnome-session-properties`, then `Add`:

*Name*: `Whatever`
*Command*: `xmodmap -e 'keysym KP_Prior = Prior' -e 'keysym KP_Next = Next'`
*Comment*: `Whatever`

Alternatively, create a file `~/.Xmodmap` with this content:

```
keysym KP_Prior = Prior
keysym KP_Next = Next
```

test if it works with:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Load it at start-up with `xmodmap /home/yourusername/.Xmodmap`, via `gnome-session-properties`, `xinitrc`, `xprofile`. E.g. (note the full path for the file):

`gnome-session-properties` >> `Add` :

*Name*: `Whatever`
*Command*: `xmodmap /home/tshepang/.Xmodmap`
*Comment*: `Whatever`