# Tab switching shortcut in xfce4 terminal only shows 5~ or ;5~

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

According to the menu settings in my xfce 4.16 terminal on Xubuntu Impish, I should be able to switch to the previous tab with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and to the next with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd>, but when I press these, it only prints `5~` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and `;5~` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd>.

This is on a System76 Gazelle laptop with numberpad and numlock is off. When I turn numlock on, I get `9` instead of <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and `3` instead of <kbd>PgDown</kbd>. It does work with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cursor up</kbd> / Cursor down.

[image: Image of the keyboard]

Redshift is not installed. These keyboard shortcuts work fine in e.g., Firefox.

How can I use these keyboard shortcuts to switch tabs?

Comment: Which laptop model? Could you post a link to an actual keyboard image ? Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76278/how-to-make-ctrlpgup-and-ctrlpgdn-change-window-tabs and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607326/ctrlpageup-and-ctrl-pagedown-suddenly-stopped-working

Comment: Please try the other PgUp (not the one with a number but the one **above** it, the one with **Pause**)

Comment: Thanks for the links, @IsaaC The xmodmap configuration from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76333/48820 fixed it. Feel free to close this as duplicate. Or should I delete it?